# Regex matching except whitespace in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to match on a white space followed by anything except whitespace [i.e. letters, punctuation] at the start of a line  in Python. For example:

```
 ` a`  = True
 ` .` = True
 `  a`  = False    [double whitespace]
 `ab` = False      [no whitespace]
```

The rule `re.match(" \w")` works except with punctuation - how do i include that?

Comment: @JavaNut13 - thanks!! - and sorry, should have been able to figure that myself!

Comment: "unlike regex in other languages, i couldn't find an option in Python for everything except whitespace" - oh really? well, you need the same syntax. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html `\S` is right below `\s`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remember the following:

```
\s\S
```

- `\s` is whitespace
- `\S` is everything but whitespace

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"(?<=^\s)[^\s]+.*")

print r.findall(" a")
print r.findall(" .")
print r.findall("  a")
print r.findall("ab")
```

output:

```
['a']
['.']
[]
[]
```

regex explanation:

- (?<=^\s) - positive lookbehind, matches whitespace at the beginning of string
- [^\s]+ - any non whitespace character repeated one or more times
- .* - any character repeated zero or more times